# Progress bar increment by 1 every 100th of second

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to get a `JProgressBar` to increment by 1 every 100th of a second, and at the moment I'm using `Thread.sleep(100)` inside a while statement like so:

```
    try {
         while (i<=100){
            doTime();

         }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SplashScreen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

public void doTime() throws InterruptedException{


        jLabel1.setText("sleeping");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        jLabel1.setText("start");
        i++;
        pb.setValue(i);
        pb.repaint();

}
```

and If I debug by doing a `System.out.println` it displays in real time but the swing GUI freezes until it drops out of the while loop can anyone help?

thanks

matt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As derivation said, you should use [SwingWorker](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). From its javadoc:

"SwingWorker is designed for situations where you need to have a **long running task run in a background thread and provide updates to the UI either when done, or while processing.** Subclasses of SwingWorker must implement the doInBackground()  method to perform the background computation."

With this slight change to [ProgressBarDemo.java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ProgressBarDemoProject/src/components/ProgressBarDemo.java) in the java tutorial, you almost get what you want.

```
    public Void doInBackground() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int progress = 0;
        //Initialize progress property.
        setProgress(0);
        while (progress < 100) {
            //Sleep for up to one second.
            try {
                //original code: Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000));
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}
            //Make random progress.
            //originalcode: progress += random.nextInt(10);
            progress++;
            setProgress(Math.min(progress, 100));
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are sleeping the Swing Event thread. You'll want to create a new thread for running the loop, and then have that loop update the progressbar on the swing event thread.

I would use the [Swing Worker thread](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads2.html) for the loop. Then use [invokeLater](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) for updating the progressbar.

Another good [swing/thread tutorial](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html).

Answer (score 1):

Besides what derivation said, you are sleeping for 100 milliseconds.  That means you are only updating every tenth of a second, not every hundredth.

Answer (score 1):

If `doTime()` is being called within the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT), which it should since it is calling UI code (`jLabel1.setText()` and others), then it should *not* be calling `sleep()` at all. You do not want to freeze your UI.

The correct way of doing this is to use a [timer](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to wake up in the correct moments (say, every 10 ms) and update the progress. The code by **Jala** is also a good answer, and it is the official Swing Way of doing things (timers are lower level than SwingWorkers).

Comment: +1 Here's a simple example of `javax.swing.Timer` updating a `JLabel` every 100 ms. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576353/stop-a-stopwatch/2576909#2576909