# Having a problem getting my ActionListeners, Handlers, and GUI to communicate

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

So I am trying to get my GUI to work. When I run the code below, it does nothing, and I'm sure I'm probably just doing something dumb, but I am completely stuck...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    UI.getInstance().sS++;

    if((UI.getInstance().sS %2) != 0){
        UI.getInstance().startStop.setName("STOP");
        UI.getInstance().change.setEnabled(false);
    }else if(UI.getInstance().sS%2 == 0){
        UI.getInstance().startStop.setName("START");
        UI.getInstance().change.setEnabled(true);
    }


}

public void setStartListener(StartHandler e){
    this.startStop.addActionListener(e);
}
```

sS is an int that increments every time the button startStop is clicked. change is also a button.

Comment: did you add the ActionListener to the button that is suppose to run all that? viz did you call setStartListener()?

Comment: I did not instantiate StartListener in my test class. I knew it was something dumb...thanks for drawing my attention to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576353/stop-a-stopwatch/2576909#2576909) that shows a different approach to managing a `Start/Stop` button. It uses an instance of [`javax.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to pace updates. Encapsulating the control button and display label may simplify maintenance. This [variation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9255847/230513) illustrates adding a third command to pause updates.

```
private static final String Start = "Start";
private static final String Stop = "Stop";
…
private static void create() {
    …
    final JButton button = new JButton(Stop);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
            if (Stop.equals(cmd)) {
                jtl.stop();
                button.setText(Start);
            } else {
                jtl.start();
                button.setText(Stop);
            }

        }
    });
    …
}
```

More generally, use [`Action`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) to encapsulate functionality for use elsewhere in your program. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37063037/230513) "exports several actions that make it easy to use them in a control panel."

[image]

Answer (score 2):

not really an answer, but I think your code would be simpler if you used a boolean instead of an int, something like:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    final boolean isEnabled = UI.getInstance().change.isEnabled();
    if(isEnabled){
        UI.getInstance().startStop.setName("STOP");
    }else{
        UI.getInstance().startStop.setName("START");
    }
    UI.getInstance().change.setEnabled(!isEnabled); 
}
```