# How to stop timer in a swing application

Tags: java, swing, timer, timertask

I wrote a little code to change the colours of a few buttons to stimulate a random sequence offlashing colours. i have set a timer to do this for me but i just dont know how to stop it

Heres my code

```
          Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        int buttons[] = new int[9];

                        for (int j = 0; j < buttons.length; j++) {

                        //  System.out.println("times");
                            Component button = frame.getContentPane().getComponent(j);
                            int Red = new Random().nextInt(255 - 1) + 1;
                            int Green = new Random().nextInt(255 - 1) + 1;
                            int Blue = new Random().nextInt(255 - 1) + 1;

                            button.setBackground(new Color(Red, Green, Blue));

                            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(button);

                        }

                    }// }

                }); timer.start();
```

Comment: You'll need to call the stop() method on the Timer object. When/how do you want it to stop?

Comment: create a variable.then increment it when timer tick.stop timer when variable value reach 8

Comment: @fastsnil  i have tried to create an integer variable counter and increment it in the for loop but doesn't work, can you perhaps show me what you mean with code?

Comment: @d.j.brown  i want it to stop after a lapse of time let say after 10 seconds. i want it to stop by itself i tried to use the stop()  method but it stops the timer before it even starts

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37063037/230513).

Comment: Don't use `updateComponentTree(...)`!!! There is no need to use that method. All you need to do is invoke the setBackground() method and the component will repaint itself. `increment it in the for loop but doesn't work,` - no you don't increment it in the for loop. You increment it at the end of the actionPerformed() method. Then when if reaches 10 you stop the Timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few ways you can do it, here's a couple of quick approaches.

One method is by utilising `System.currentTimeMillis()`:

```
private Timer timer;
private final int DELAY = 100;
private final int DURATION = 10_000;
private long startTime;

public void timerExample() {
    timer = new Timer(DELAY, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= startTime + DURATION) {
                System.out.println("Done");
                timer.stop();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Tick");
            }
        }
    });
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    timer.start();
}
```

This one will stop the `Timer` if the current time is greater than the `startTime` + `DURATION`.

Another method is this use of a counter:

```
private Timer timer;
private final int DELAY = 100;
private final int DURATION = 10_000;
private final int TOTAL_TICKS = DURATION / DELAY;
private int tickCounter = 0;

public void timerExample() {
    timer = new Timer(DELAY, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (++tickCounter == TOTAL_TICKS) {
                System.out.println("Done");
                timer.stop();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Tick");
            }
        }
    });
    timer.start();
}
```

With `DELAY` as 100ms and `DURATION` as 10,000ms you can calculate the total number of Timer *ticks* required e.g. 10,000 / 100 = 100 ticks.

Each time action listener is fired, it checks if the total number of ticks are reached, and if so stops the timer.