# Setting java awt mouse event without creating class?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am doing awt work, but awt is not easy compared with JavaFX I learned before, I am struggling in setting an event for the button in the frame, and I have a PlayAgain() method, my aim is to call the method when the button is clicked. Additional: please do not create an inner class such to implement some Handlers, and justing using **awt** rather than swing/Fx.

This is my code:

```
public class CircleDraw extends Frame{
int[] diceResults;

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    //in this part, I just using Graphics drawing some circles.
}

public void PlayAgain() {
    //......do something
}


public static void main(String args[]) {
    Frame frame = new CircleDraw();
    Button button = new Button("again!");//this is the button, I want to set a Event, when clicking the button,my program will call PlayAgain() method
    frame.add(button);
    button.setBounds(5, 5, 5, 5);
    frame.add(button);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    frame.setSize(500, 250);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

I remember in JavaFX it indeed could be written like this:

```
button.setMouseClicked(e -> {
      //call the method}  )
```

So is there something similar in the awt could do this?

Comment: " please do not create an inner class " - is that _your_ requirement? Note that even `e -> { /*call the method*/ }` will create an anonymous inner class. For action listeners you could use lambdas, i.e. `button.addActionListener( e -> { ... } ) `, for other listeners like mouse listeners that would not be so easy as the interfaces don't meet the requirements (you could provide some form of builder that accepts lambdas though).

Comment: Use `Action`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37063037/230513); see also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way around creating a class. This is required by Java's strong typing. However, you do have some choices that you might find better than others.

- You can create a lambda function directly.
- You can have a compatible method signature and use it as a lambda function.
- You can implement the listener in your top-level class, ie. CircleDraw implements WindowListener.
- You can declare a field in CircleDraw and make it an instance of anonymous class.
- You can use an anonymous class as a parameter (as per your example)
- You can use a named inner class (you said you don't like that).

All of them are merely syntactic sugar. Behind the scenes, there is always a class that implements WindowAdapter.