# How to use a sleep/wait function to display a countdown

Tags: java, timer, sleep, wait, countdown

I want my program to start off using a countdown timer that will be displayed to the user. The only way I can think to do that is to label.setText() and Thread.sleep(). I've tried for about 20min trying to get it to work, but can't seem to crack it. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Swing timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). Basically you create a class that implements `ActionListener`, create a `javax.swing.Timer`, and the `actionPerformed` method of the `ActionListener` gets called at an interval you specify. In your `actionPerformed` method, check the time, and update the value to be displayed when appropropriate, and call `repaint()`. Use an interval of 0.1 second, and your countdown will be smooth and accurate enough.

Comment: +1 for `javax.swing.Timer`; there's a related count-up example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2576909/230513).

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this man! Got it working. It's actually part of a project for my matric IT PAT.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't count on the accuracy of `Thread.sleep`, but:

```
for(int i = 20; i >= 0; i--) {
   label.setText(i + " seconds remaining");
   Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

This will, of course, block the UI thread while sleeping, so you probably need to run it on a separate thread. This means you will need something like `SwingUtilities.InvokeLater` to update the UI, since you are using a thread different than the UI one:

```
for(int i = 20; i >= 0; i--) {
   SwingUtilities.InvokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             label.setText(i + " seconds remaining");
         }
       });
   Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: Not this. You shouldn't call any Swing methods except on the event thread, and you can't sleep on the event thread since the screen will then not repaint; so this can never be the right solution. Animation always must involve a second thread.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill: And what am I doing in the above code? You probably posted while I was adding the explanation and the second code snippet.

Comment: +1 for the alternative, but `javax.swing.Timer` is more convenient.