# Swing GUI not updating

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, concurrency, swingworker

I'm writing an application that reads in audio, analyses this data and then displays the results in realtime. Currently I am using a SwingWorker to run the loop that initiates the background analysis and calling the SwingUtilities.invokeLater method inside the loop to update the GUI components each time analysis has completed. At the moment, the GUI seems to be updating randomly, and occasionally not at all.

The following code shows how I'm trying to accomplish this. The TunerListener is an inner class of a JPanel subclass. PrevNote, nextNote, frequency, and the light variables are all components in the JPanel subclass that I want to update:

```
private class TunerListener implements ActionListener {
    private boolean firstUpdate = true;
    private boolean executing = false;
    private TunerWorker tunerWorker = null;

    private final class TunerWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() {
            while (!this.isCancelled()) {

                // Audio analysis in worker thread
                model.update(firstUpdate);

                // Update components in EDT
                if (!this.isCancelled()) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            prevNote.setText(model.getPrev());
                            currentNote.setText(model.getNote());
                            nextNote.setText(model.getNext());
                            frequency.setText("Frequency: "
                                    + model.getFrequency());
                            switch (model.getOffset()) {
                                case -2:
                                    light_2.setIcon(onRed);
                                    light_1.setIcon(off);
                                    light0.setIcon(offBig);
                                    light1.setIcon(off);
                                    light2.setIcon(off);
                                    break;
                                case -1:
                                    light_2.setIcon(off);
                                    light_1.setIcon(onRed);
                                    light0.setIcon(offBig);
                                    light1.setIcon(off);
                                    light2.setIcon(off);
                                    break;
                                case 0:
                                    light_2.setIcon(off);
                                    light_1.setIcon(off);
                                    light0.setIcon(onGreen);
                                    light1.setIcon(off);
                                    light2.setIcon(off);
                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    light_2.setIcon(off);
                                    light_1.setIcon(off);
                                    light0.setIcon(offBig);
                                    light1.setIcon(onRed);
                                    light2.setIcon(off);
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    light_2.setIcon(off);
                                    light_1.setIcon(off);
                                    light0.setIcon(offBig);
                                    light1.setIcon(off);
                                    light2.setIcon(onRed);
                                    break;
                            }
                            firstUpdate = false;
                        }
                    });
                }

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
        }

    };

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("tune")) {
            if (!executing) {
                executing = true;
                firstUpdate = true;
                tune.setText("Stop Tuning");
                tunerWorker = new TunerWorker();
                tunerWorker.execute();
            } else {
                tune.setText("Start Tuning");
                executing = false;
                tunerWorker.cancel(true);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Edit**
I notice when I use the debugger that I sometimes get to a point where it tells me the source could not be found and in the debugging window it says something about a FutureTask$Sync.innerRun. Does this narrow it down at all?

Comment: Have you tried validate() and repaint() methods for GUI components or frames ?

Comment: I don't think you need to put your code inside `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` thingy, this is SwingWorker. Since, moreover it seems to me, that your content that you trying to update is all `String` (if I am not mistaken), then you can simply call `publish()`, which will inturn invoke `process(...)` that if always on EDT. And I guess the second argument to your `SwingWorker<Void, String>` should have to be `String` instead of `Void`

Comment: for better help sooner edit you quesion with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, use an instance of `javax.swing.Timer`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2576909/230513), to <kbd>Start</kbd> and <kbd>Stop</kbd> the playing of a selected `Note`, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2065693/230513). The `play()` method feeds a `SourceDataLine`, which operates asynchronously, and the `enum Note` makes constructing a `JComboBox` particularly easy.

[image: Note]

```
final JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
for (Note note : Note.values()) {
    combo.addItem(note);
}
combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(combo.getSelectedItem());
    }
});
this.add(combo);
```